# What is wrong with my meteor leaderboard example?

Tags: meteor

I've just installed Meteor and I'm having a look at the leaderboard example.

I'm trying to set a random score, can't see what's wrong with my code.  Can anyone see what's wrong with this?  I'm expecting that when the button is clicked the selected player score is populated with random numbers.

Template code:

```
<template name="leaderboard">
<div class="leaderboard">
{{#each players}}
  {{> player}}
{{/each}}
</div>

{{#if selected_name}}
<div class="details">
<div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
 <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
 <input type="button" class="incrandom" value="Set random points" />
</div>
{{else}}
<div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

JS code:

```
  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.incrandom': function () {
    Players.update(session.get("selected_player"), {$incrandom: {score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5 }});
    }
  });
```

Comment: First: change `session` to `Session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$incrandom` operator in MongoDB, only [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Also, what is `Random` in this code snippet? You probably meant to use `Math.random()`.

Also (thank you @apendua, I didn't notice this), `session` should be `Session`.

So the updated code would be:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click input.incrandom': function () {
    Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)*5 }});
    }
  });
```

Note, however, that this does not **set** the player's score to a random value but **increments** the player's score by a random value.

To set the player's score use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator instead.

Comment: That's great, thank you for both your replies.

I did intend Random.fraction as that's what's in the server part of the example.  I thought $inc was referring to the class in some way, never used Mongo before either.  All new to me, so thank you very much for your help with this!

Comment: You are welcome. And you are right about using `Random`, I wasn't aware of the `random` package that ships with Meteor.